Parent class without table, extended by two entities with different tables. Parent class mapped in different class with @OneToMany
I have three java classes: CommonBon (parent class), Bon extends CommonBon and BonHistory extends CommonBon.
On database side there are two tables: Bon and BonHistory. They have different ids(BON_ID and BON_HISTORY_ID).
I also have another abstract class CommonProduct with annotation @MappedSuperclass which contains:
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@OrderBy("displayNo")
private Set<CommonBon> bons = new LinkedHashSet<>();

is it technically possible in Hibernate to have @Id annotation in CommonBon and somehow override it in two extending classes Bon and BonHistory?
I also tried to add @Id in Bon and @Id in BonHistory and annotate CommonBon with @MappedSuperclass but it's also impossible because then hibernate shout out that I am trying to join @OneToMany with CommonBon which is not entity. On the other hand to annotate CommonBon with @Entity I need @Id.
What should be solution for this?

Try turning CommonBon into an entity and annotate it with @Inheritance(strategy = TABLE_PER_CLASS). This will make sure that Bon and BonHistory have their own table. I think (but I'm not 100% sure) that if CommonBon is abstract it won't need its own table. Keep in mind that any SELECT involving CommonBon, including this relation, needs to use a UNION.

Correct CommonBon doesn't need it's own table and I know how to solve it but problem is slighty different - if I move @Id to Bon and  another @Id to BonHistory then this @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true) @OrderBy("displayNo") private Set<CommonBon> bons = new LinkedHashSet<>(); doesn't work in abstract class CommonProduct

Can't you keep the @Id in CommonBon?

@RobSpoor, but in hierarchy hibernate allows just one @Id. If I keep @Id in CommonBon then I won't be able use @Id in Bon and BonHistory
